# return size of the group in each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to return the size of each run above a target value in a dataframe, so far I've only managed to return a running count of the size of the group using

```
df.groupby((df["value"] < df["target"]).cumsum()).cumcount()
```

| value | target | current code result | desired result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 5 | 1 | 3 |
| 7 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 5 | 3 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Can you give a little more information about your desired output. F.e. why is the output of the first 5-5 (row 0) = 0, but the second 5-5 (row 4) should be included in the group (value = 4)

Comment: AFAIU all you should do is to [count()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) on the results of `groupby()`.

Comment: how do you get 4?

Comment: sorry Paul and Enke, my mistake- table edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make this a bit more interesting by having two runs in the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['value','target'], data = [[5, 5], 
[6, 5], 
[7, 5], 
[6, 5], 
[5, 5],
[6, 5], 
[7, 5], 
[6, 5], 
[5, 5],
])
```

Then we groupby on a combination of two conditions that mark the start and end of a run, and calculate the length in the run assigning it to `runcount`:

```
(df.groupby(
    [(df['value'] <= df['target']).cumsum(), 
      df['value'] > df['target']
      ])
   .apply(lambda g: g.assign(runcount = (g['value']>g['target']).sum()))
   .reset_index(drop = True)
)
```

output

```
      value    target    runcount
--  -------  --------  ----------
 0        5         5           0
 1        6         5           3
 2        7         5           3
 3        6         5           3
 4        5         5           0
 5        6         5           3
 6        7         5           3
 7        6         5           3
 8        5         5           0
```